# Async/await function return undefined

Tags: node.js, async-await, undefined

Yes I search before and yes this is annother question about await/async function...

I'm sorry in advance if my question is a duplicate but I don't found solution...

```js
// get result of a poll
async function foo(param) {
    const REACT_OPTS = ['1️⃣', '2️⃣', '3️⃣', '4️⃣', '5️⃣', '6️⃣', '7️⃣', '8️⃣', '9️⃣', ' '];
    const opts = {
        'key': 'val',
        'other_key': 'other_val'
    };
    const baz = await get_array_baz(param);
    let results = {
        total: 0,
        tab: []
    };

    let r = 0;
    baz.each(function(obj) {
        results.total += obj.num;
        results.tab.push({
            count: obj.num,
            emoji: REACT_OPTS[r]
        });
        r++;
    });

    console.log('results', results);
    return {opts, results};
}

// close a poll
async function bar() {
    // Get poll opts/results and publish channel
    const { opts, res } = await foo(param);
    console.log('bar', opts, res);
}
```

**console.log**

```
> results {
    total: 3,
        tab: [
        { num: 1, emoji: '1️⃣' },
        { num: 0, emoji: '2️⃣' },
        { num: 0, emoji: '3️⃣' },
        { num: 1, emoji: '4️⃣' },
        { num: 0, emoji: '5️⃣' },
        { num: 0, emoji: '6️⃣' },
        { num: 1, emoji: '7️⃣' }
    ]
}
> bar {
    key: 'val',
    other_key: 'other_val'
} undefined
```

How it is possible ? One line can log result, the next line is undefined... And more strange : why `opts` can pass and not `results` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are exporting  **`{opts, results}`** from **foo** function. And in **bar**
 function you must destructure  with same name like `{ opts, results }` instead of `{ opts, res }` .

**try to run your code again by using below bar function :**

```
async function bar() {
    // Get poll opts/results and publish channel
    const { opts, results } = await foo(param);
    console.log('bar', opts, results);
}
```

Still if you want to use res then provide alias for results like `const { opts, results:res } = await foo(param);`

Comment: Thank you !!! I'm feeling so stupid.... Now I better understand how work extract mod.